# user-inactivity auto logout

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, user-inactivity

I want to implement an auto user logout after an idle time of X mins in my project. So I have googled for relevant examples but they cant seem to debug properly with my existing codes. My intentions are to utilize:

-a BackgroundProcessingService extend Service
-a CountDownTimer

Can anyone help me with a basic auto user logout program?

Answer (score 1):

> How you can achieve user-inactivity auto logout:

- Use your ideal XX minute in prefrences.
- start an AlarmManager with the help of BroadcastReceiver.
- the ideal time you want put in the AlarmManager and when Receiver called , call Logout programmatically.

**I used these step and it's working.**

If you have any problem with these step.

feel free to ask

Comment: what do you mean by use my ideal XX minutes in preferences?? could you please illustrate?

Comment: I have added this code into my existing program, but when debugged, it doesn't work, pls advise:

Comment: have you declare Broadcast Receiver in Manifest file

Comment: no code now, I made this demo along back. Please try these stepand let me know if you faced any issue @RaseemAyatt